# Fit d3.hexbin visualization into svg element

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to fit d3.js hexbin visualization into the selected svg element.
However, at least the outer hexagons are cut into half by the element border. I tried applying a smaller width and height to the hexbin scaling but it does seem to have any effect.
Maybe there is something wrong with the viewBox?

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

```js
var rect = document.querySelector('#dash'),
    width = rect.offsetWidth,
    height = rect.offsetHeight;

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 50, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60}

var svg = d3.select("div#dash")
.append("svg")
 .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
 .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + String(2000) + " " +  String(2000) )
 .classed("svg-content", true)
 .append("g")
 
var randomX = d3.randomNormal(width, 80)
var randomY = d3.randomNormal(height, 80)

points = d3.range(200).map(function() { return [randomX(), randomY()]; });

var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateLab("white", "blue")).domain([0, 20]);

var graph_width = width - width/10
var graph_height = height - height/10

var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
    .size([graph_width, graph_height])
    .radius(20);

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll(".hexagon")
    .data(hexbin(points))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "hexagon")
    .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon())
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.length); });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>


<body>

<div id="dash" class="svg-container"></div>    
    
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set svg's `width` and `height` explicitly
2. Remove `viewBox`
3. Use simple randomization

```js
const rect = document.querySelector('#dash');
const width = rect.offsetWidth;
const height = rect.offsetHeight;
const radius = 20;

const svg = d3.select("div#dash")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
 .classed("svg-content", true)
 .append("g")
 
points = d3.range(200)
  .map(function() { return [Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height]; })
  .filter(point => point[0] > radius && point[0] < width - radius * 2 && point[1] > radius && point[1] < height - radius);

const color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateLab("white", "blue")).domain([0, 20]);

var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
.size([width, height])
.radius(radius);

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll(".hexagon")
.data(hexbin(points))
  .enter().append("path")
.attr("class", "hexagon")
.attr("d", hexbin.hexagon())
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.length); });
```

```css
#dash {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>

<div id="dash" class="svg-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Maybe I was not clear enough. Also in your example, the ones on the border are still cut by the element svg.  How can we prevent that and resize the hexagons so that none of them are cut?

Comment: @RaphaelB. add `filter` after `map` for points - see the fixed snippet

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves the issue addressed. So I will mark this as solved. 
However, filtering out overlapping datapoints would not be a good practice when we engage real data. I was hoping for a solution to show all appended hexagons - maybe the solution is very simple here....